# Can I solder a laptop fuse in parallel with a burnt out fuse?

Tags: motherboard, soldering

I have a MacBook pro with a burnt out led-fuse. I haven't found any shorted components yet, so I wanted to try to replace the fuse, but I assume soldering a fuse parallel to a fuse would be easier than removing a fuse from a logic board and soldering a new one in its place. Does this create any kind of issue I am unaware of?

Comment: You may get some replies here but other than that, you could try asking in electronics stackexchange chat but that would probably require more rep points than the 1 you have. So maybe an electronics forum

Comment: Other than the obvious points that the old one burned out for a reason that still isn't fixed, and you need to replace it with an identical one, there's no issue from an electrical standpoint.

Comment: @fixer1234 Okay, thanks. I've been checking a lot of the components close to the backlight fuse and haven't found any shorted components so far.